# Does java do some round off to avoid imprecision in IEEE-754 representation

Tags: java, ieee-754

I recently came across a problem where I had to think about the imprecision in representing floats. But to my surprise, I didn't find the errors that I expected. I created a simple example code for describing my question

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        float one_point_six = 1.6f; // According to IEEE-754, should be 1.60000002384185791015625
        float zero_point_four = 0.4f; // According to IEEE-754, should be 0.4000000059604644775390625
        float sum = one_point_six + zero_point_four; // shouldn't this be 2.0000000298023223876953125?

        System.out.println(Math.ceil(sum)); // Prints 2.0. Shouldn't this be 3?
        System.out.println(sum > 2f); // Prints false. Why?
    }
}
```

The output remains the same even if I replace floats with doubles. Is Java doing some round-offs or am I missing something?
I used https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html for finding out the "actual" value that's being stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> shouldn't this be 2.0000000298023223876953125?

No. As you know, `float` has limited precision, so it is not precise enough to store a number of that precision. Trying using your converter, and entering 2.0000000298023223876953125 in there, you will find that the actual value stored is just "2".

Comment: Yeah, that makes perfect sense. In order to verify this, I changed the data type of sum from float to double and added a cast to double for one_point_six while summing. That gave me the outputs 3 & true. Thanks!